# problems trying to install PIP

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming, code, pip

Ugh I'm so frustrated. I'm trying to install pip for vscode so I can get py-solc-x. I downloaded python (it shows that I'm on python 3.10.12 when i run python --version). But when I run install python3-pip or sudo apt install python3-pip I get this mess of errors. I also tried to first run "sudo apt-get update" and I get a bunch of errors like "E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1d 7h 19min 28s). Updates for this repository will not be applied" which seem to relate to the errors when installing pip.

Errors running sudo apt install python3-pip:

[image]

Comment: These errors look like it's unable to connect to http://archive.ubuntu.com/ (http://185.125.190.39/). It looks like this site is up, but not accepting https connections, only http. Have you tried installing pip outside of vscode?